I want to apply reinforcement learning to a manipulator. Seeking advice!
I am a university student currently studying reinforcement learning. I am trying to apply RL to a manipulator for the first time and feel a bit overwhelmed, so I would greatly appreciate any advice you can offer.

Simulator Recommendations: I’m not sure which simulator is best suited for applying RL to a manipulator. I’ve heard of PyBullet, MuJoCo, Gazebo, and several others. Which simulator is the most widely used and recommended?
Paper Recommendations: If you know of any key papers or review articles on applying reinforcement learning to manipulators, I would be grateful for your recommendations. Especially as a beginner, I’d like to know which papers I should start with.
Recommended Study Resources: If there are any websites or resources with well-organized study materials for this field, I would appreciate any recommendations. Alternatively, if you have a suggested curriculum or study path for applying RL to manipulators, that would be incredibly helpful.

Any resources or advice for a beginner would be greatly appreciated! Thank you all in advance.
